# How to work with several forms of the same type at the same time - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form for adding an item - its name, its price, the date when it was bought and some notes. But since there will be a lot of items, it will be uncomfortable to submit each one by itself. What I want to do is to repeat the form several times and with one commit several items to go to the databae. Something like this:

```
Name | Price | Date | Notes
Name | Price | Date | Notes
Name | Price | Date | Notes

Submit
```

where the user will write and commit 3 items at once. Sorry for the bad explaining, I hope that it won't be too messy. I should implement this with Symfony2. Thank you very much for the  help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about embeded forms. Or collection widget.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I didn't even know how is this called to search it in google. I will read it :)